# Need a flow to output number of unique values on a related list

Tags: visual-workflow, update, loop, count

I have a custom object called "Issue" with a related list to another custom object called "Impacted Contacts." There's a join record called "Issue Impacted Contacts." I need to make a flow that will look at "Impacted Contacts" related to the "Issue" record and output the unique number of States; which is a field on the "Issue Impacted Contacts" record.

So we may have 50 people impacted and would want to know if all 50 are in 1 state or if there are 2 states (40 in CA and 10 in NY) or 3 (10 CA, 10 NY and 30 TX). I don't care about the number of impacted in each state just the total states involved.

Someone at work stepped through what they thought I'd need but they aren't available anymore and the instructions were in their org using standard SF objects so I'm having a hard time translating them and he was in a hurry so I only got a couple of screenshots worth anything.

From my coworkers diagram I nee:

```
GetRecords
--Into--
Decision --Into-- Assignment --Into-- Update
--Into--
Loop
--Into--
Decision
--Into--
Assignment
--Into--
Loop (from line 5)
```

Anyone available to help? This would be my first attempt at a flow and I have the pieces (I think) except the necessary variables.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't fully do this with a Flow because Flows cannot react to delete events. I'd recommend looking at [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), which with a little cleverness _can_ get this done for you without code.

Comment: @DavidReed deleting isn't really an issue. These "Issues' only matter for a few weeks in most times so we wouldn't make any updates to them after a month or so.

So can everything but the deletes be done in a flow?

Comment: Yes, you can write a Flow to roll up data provided you don't mind that deletions will be ignored.